# Spring Batch CompositeItemWriter How to properly set writer delegates

Tags: java, spring-batch

Hi I am trying to add two writers to a spring batch compositeitemwriter. I am getting an error saying:

```
The method setDelegates(List<ItemWriter<? super MyObject>>) in the type CompositeItemWriter<MyObject> is not applicable for the arguments (List<ItemWriter<MyObject>>)
```

My code below

```
public ItemWriter<MyObject> myWriter(){
    ItemWriter<MyObject> myWriter = new myWriter();
    return myWriter;
}

public ItemWriter<MyObject> myOtherWriter(){
    ItemWriter<MyObject> myOtherWriter = new MyOtherWriter();
    return myOtherWriter;
}

public CompositeItemWriter<MyObject> compositeItemWriter(){
    CompositeItemWriter<MyObject> writer = new CompositeItemWriter<MyObject>();
    List<ItemWriter<MyObject>> writerList = new ArrayList<ItemWriter<MyObject>>();
    writerList.add(myWriter());
    writerList.add(myOtherWriter());
    writer.setDelegates(writerList); //<-- ERROR HERE
    return writer;
}
```

I could not find any strong code examples of compositeitemwriters that did not use xml. I know my error has something to do with generic type parameters, which I have little knowledge of. Could anyone explain why the above code would not work and possibly how to remedy it? [Multiple itemwriters in Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915688/multiple-itemwriters-in-spring-batch/39175542#39175542) This is the closest I could find, but it uses generic types which also give me an error.

Thank you for any help! I am new to spring batch.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying...

```
List<ItemWriter<MyObject>> writerList = new ArrayList<ItemWriter<MyObject>>();
```

...with :

```
List<ItemWriter<? super MyObject>> writerList = new ArrayList<ItemWriter<? super MyObject>>();
```

---

`CompositeItemWriter#setDelegates` takes a list in the form `List<ItemWriter<? super T>>`.

See [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html#setDelegates(java.util.List)).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you did not find a proper solution.
I would do it like this:

```
public ItemWriter<MyObject> myWriter() {
    ItemWriter<MyObject> myWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyObject>(); //  <-- Example item writer 1
    return myWriter;
}

public ItemWriter<MyObject> myOtherWriter() {
    ItemWriter<MyObject> myOtherWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyObject>(); //  <-- Example item writer 2
    return myOtherWriter;
}

public CompositeItemWriter<MyObject> compositeItemWriter() {
    CompositeItemWriter<MyObject> writer = new CompositeItemWriter<MyObject>();
    writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(myWriter(),myOtherWriter())); //<-- NO ERROR HERE :)
    return writer;
}
```

I hope that helps.