# Spring Batch - write to 2 tables at once

Tags: java, spring-batch, writers

I have a Person object that has a list of addresses. My Spring Batch app converts Person JSON recors into Person POJOs and writes them to a database.

Ordinarily, I'd use JdbcBatchItemWriter but I see it is limited in writing to 2 seperate tables. I need to write to Person and Address table.

Hibernate could write this in one step but I don't see a simialr capability in Spring Bathc.

This SO question [Multiple itemwriters in Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915688/multiple-itemwriters-in-spring-batch?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) suggests using a CompositeItemWriter but the issue with that is, I want my Address table to hold a column called Person_id to link an address back to Person. I won't be able to do that with 2 writes.

Any suggestions? Surely Batch caters for more complex writes

Comment: you can use hibernate in your ItemWriter, just call your PersonService in it to save all the data, or it's something wrong with that?

Comment: @KacperWolkowski I cannot introduce Hibernate unfortunately

Comment: This doesn't invalidate @KacperWolkowski; with SB compose your object and with PersonService persist it with your technology (hibernate, jdbc or any other one you are using for persistence)

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci He suggested using Hibernate inside an ItemWriter. As per my question, ItemWriter's only write to one database table.

Comment: Yes. But he also suggested to make a call to `PersonService#save(Person)` in `ItemWriter`. And in `PersonService` you can use your preferred technology.

Answer (score 5):

I see from the comment that you can't use an ORM or a service that persists a Person with its addresses. In this case, you can use a custom writer for that:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class PersonWriter implements ItemWriter<Person> {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public PersonWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Person> items) {
        for (Person person : items) {
            jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO Person ...");
            for (Address address : person.addresses) {
                jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO Address ... where person_id = ?", person.getId()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to do it to delegate to two jdbc batch item writers:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;

public class PersonItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Person> {

    private JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> personWriter;
    private JdbcBatchItemWriter<Address> addressWriter;

    public PersonItemWriter(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> personWriter, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Address> addressWriter) {
        this.personWriter = personWriter;
        this.addressWriter = addressWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Person> persons) throws Exception {
        for (Person person : persons) {
            personWriter.write(Collections.singletonList(person));
            List<Address> addresses = person.getAddresses();
            for (Address address : addresses) {
                address.setPersonId(person.getId());
            }
            addressWriter.write(addresses);
        }
    }
}
```