# Spring batch one file with data for 3 diferent tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Hello i'm new using Spring Batch, I've a problem where i work, we have one .Txt file where just one line has data to be insert in 3 diferent tables, its possible to do using spring batch? Or is just better to insert all data in a single table and then use sql do join this data?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes - consider using a `CompositeItemWriter`, where each writer handles a different table (Repository).  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915688/multiple-itemwriters-in-spring-batch) is a related answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple itemwriters in Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915688/multiple-itemwriters-in-spring-batch)